# Immunology Book Suggestion

Tags: homework, immunology, book-recommendation

Which book will give a brief account about B-cell development so that it covers two questions about the following cells:

- Plasmablast
- Plasma cell
- Memory B cell
- Marginal zone (MZ) B cell
- B-1 cell
- B-2 cell
- Regulatory B (Breg) cell

  1. Where do they lie in the *course of B-cell development and differentiation*?
  2. What are their functions (outline)?

P.S. I need to know the development part in details rather than the functions.

Comment: http://www.amazon.in/Kuby-Immunology-International-Judy-Owen/dp/1464137846/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1477876761&sr=1-1&keywords=kuby I feel is the best for learning.. But as said, for something like immunology, you must complement a text with nature reviews

Comment: You should probably check out a review. Most basic textbooks will not delve into the various subtypes. Wikipedia has entries on all these types of cells. Did you not find that informative?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Not really, that's why I posted here. Besides I'm skeptic about wikipedia. It doesn't always contain the right information.

Comment: In this case, the wikipedia articles are not stub and they cite relevant sources. Perhaps you can clarify what exactly you are looking for. If you want detailed information then you should go for a review. For e.g. [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25902480) is a recent review on B-reg cells.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Well I have already put that in my post, questions 1 and 2. The problem with these reviews is that they though mention what the functions are but don't highlight where the cells lie in the course of B-cell development. However as a last resort I have thought of reading Kuby Immunology. I have been avoiding it because its too much detailed.

Comment: The question - "what are their functions" needs some elaboration. You can go into great level of detail with that. Kuby Immunology does not have these details; at least the version that was available 8 years ago.

Comment: Perhaps you should check this review out: http://dx.doi.org/10.1146/annurev-immunol-020711-074934

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate, as we also have a question about that: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13729/modern-immunology-textbooks

Comment: I have been through it once before. That's related but not duplicate. It's a more broad question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thank you but I don't have access to the review article. Besides I've edited the body to make more suited to Bio SE..

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh you could edit the title too as 'immunology book suggestion for following topics' or 'immunology book suggestion to get brief overview of B-cells development' or such. it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a book that explains in a quiet simple way the entire B-cell development and differentiation stepwise and covers the two questions I was looking for. It is Kuby Immunology, 7th Edition.

Except the B<sub>reg</sub> cells which is a recent discovery every cell was well discussed. I went through [this](http://www.cell.com/immunity/fulltext/S1074-7613(15)00134-X) to learn what the functions of B reg are.

Answer (score 1):

The best immunology book hands down is Janeway's Immunobiology. There is no debate among the immunology community.  The middle section is devoted to B cell development.